# how to arrange items in list box that looks like arrange in columns

Tags: asp.net, listbox, listboxitems, ironspeed

Say I have my items in list box in asp. (System.Web.UI.WebControls) :

```
100     the lonely guy     123   124
1002      the tiger's den    123   125
10     the master        125   190
10000       the talon's        231    345
```

how can i arrange it like it is formatted in columns like the format below:

```
100     the lonely guy     123   124
1002    the tiger's den    123   125
10      the master         125   190
10000   the talon's        231   345
```

hope i anyone can help me with this one.. Thank you.

Comment: Put your code in your question so that some one can understand it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    private DataSet ds;
    private MultiColumnListBox listBox1;
    public Form1()
    {
        ds = DataArray.ToDataSet(new object[,]{ 
                    {"Row0, col0",  "Row0, col1" ,1},
                    {"Row00, col0", "Row1, col1" ,new object()},
                    {"Row1, col0",  "Row2, col1" ,"Some String"},
                    {"Row1a, col0", "Row3, col1" ,Rectangle.Empty},
                    {"row1aa,col0", "Row4, col1" ,1},
                    {"row0, col0",  "Row5, col1" ,1},
                    {"pow0, col0",  "Row6, col1" ,1}
                    });

        listBox1 = new MultiColumnListBox();
        listBox1.Parent = this;

        listBox1.DataSource = arr;            
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it also available in asp.net? Because question is for asp.net.

Comment: you can use code inside function... by this you can get idea to how to achieve it!

Comment: and it is clear that i need system.web.ui.webcontrols type of listbox not system.windows.forms.form

Comment: rather then using this thing, you can use gridview, datalist or div with scrolling with better option.